# Create expanding animation on <li> button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a menu bar using a UL list.

When hovering over one of the 4 links it changed colour, what I would like is an expanding animation  almost similar to http://jsfiddle.net/xnTZq/6/ just not changing shape, it changing its colour and possibly expanding into the shape.

Below is my HTML and CSS code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .menu {
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #17ADE0;  
    }

.menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}   

.menu li {
    display: inline; 
    padding: 20px; 
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 8px 20px 6px 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #17ADE0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.menu a:active {
    color: #17ADE0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#active a {
    color: #17ADE0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.menuinfo {
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

If you require more of my code let me know.

Comment: Heres an example of something i found: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/uzgha/6/ would this be what your looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even tweak with the four transition declaration to set your animation for each transformation with custom order, delays and timing functions:

```
.menu a:hover {
  ...
  transition-property: background-color, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0, 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease;
}
```

If you want full browser compatibility, you should call each -moz, -o, -webkit and standard transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
li {
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;    
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the transition statements from the fiddle to a {} and a:hover {} and add other round edges to a:hover {}.